# Forcing and Philosophy

Tags: set-theory, badiou

The only (ontological) connection between Forcing (Cohen) and Philosophy i know is the work of Alain Badiou. Are there any other philosophers who have worked on this topic?

Comment: Writing off symbolic logic as not being part of philosophy is kind of aggressive, no?

Comment: To call something "part of philosophy" depends highly of you notion of philosophy. There is a reason I put "(ontological)".

Comment: @Averroes2, perhaps you might like to share that reason in your question? It may be helpful to know the parameters you're working with if we're to discuss possible answers.

Comment: See [here](https://seansturm.wordpress.com/2009/12/03/badiou-on-forcing/) for some treatment of Badiou's treatment of forcing. For what it's worth, I see no actual engagement with forcing as anything more than a vague idea: mathematical *language* is being used, but only to set up an analogy (and perhaps to sound intimidating).

Comment: Meanwhile, there *has* been some serious writing on the impact of forcing for philosophy of mathematics; see e.g. [here](http://logic.harvard.edu/efi.php#multimedia). Note, though, that - unlike Badiou - the authors there are only looking at forcing within the narrow context of philosophy *of mathematics* (which I'd argue is appropriate barring a very strong argument to the contrary, which in my opinion Badiou doesn't provide).

Comment: Depends on what "this topic" is. Do you mean metaphysics loosely inspired by mathematics, as in Badiou, or philosophy of modern mathematics, which would touch on higher set theory and forcing in particular? If it is the latter Maddy wrote two very illuminating papers [Believing the Axioms I](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/BLOGPAPERS/belaxioms1.pdf) and [II](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/BLOGPAPERS/belaxioms2.pdf). In the former vein see [Fraser, Law of the Subject](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/81e7/a08d3a89139507bbb32f1e2882b1cdc3574b.pdf) that touches on forcing in Badiou and Kripke.

Comment: Thank you for all the input. This helps. My question was about metaphysics inspired by mathematics, as in Badiou. I cannot find any other author than Badiou dealing with the concept of Forcing.

Comment: The use of set theory by Badiou is very controversial, and many mathematicians suggested that what he does does not really connect to the actual set theory. There was an intense debate over this between Badiou and Nirenbergs (which addresses forcing in particular), referenced [here](http://academiclogbook.blogspot.com/2012/02/nirenberg-badiou-debate-over-being-and.html) and [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.1086/662748).